# How do I open a hatch?

Tags: how-to-survive-2

On a map I can see down arrow symbols and there are hatches with two pipes on each side, but I cant seem to find a way to open them.

[image]

**Can hatches be opened? If not what can I do here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, basically you need to do the 2nd of quests the guy via intercom gives to you

You are then allowed to go downstairs by clicking <kbd>F</kbd>(Action) key